# How does \v differ from \x0b or \x0c?

Tags: python, string, escaping, whitespace

Typing `string.whitespace` gives you a string containing all whitespace characters defined by Python's `string` module:

```
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
```

Both `\x0b` and `\x0c` seem to give a vertical tab.

```
>>> print 'first\x0bsecond'
first
     second
```

`\v` gives the same effect. How are these three different? Why does the `string` module use `\x0b` or `\x0c` over the simpler `\v`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`\v` *is* `\x0b`:

```
>>> '\v'
'\x0b'
```

but the string literal representation in Python is using the `\x0b` notation instead.

The Python string literal representation only ever uses `\n`, `\r` and `\t`, everything else that is not a printable ASCII character is represented using the `\xhh` notation instead.

`\x0c` is a [*form feed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed); it forces a printer to move to the next sheet of paper. You can also express it as `\f` in Python:

```
>>> '\f'
'\x0c'
```

In terminals the effects of `\v` and `\f` are often the same.

Comment: doesn't work for me (Python 2.7.11, OSx). Any of those variations prints out a new line too.. Whitespace is \x20

Comment: @magicrebirth: sorry, what doesn't work? The variations I demonstrate are *string literals*, echoed by the interactive interpreter. And Python will *never* echo `\x20` for a space.

Comment: Nice. I ran across `\x0c` when converting OCR'd pdfs into text. The blank pages of the pdfs were returned to me as `\x0c`, which now makes perfect sense.