# backslash convert the first character of the file name in python

Tags: python, visual-studio, file

When I open a file from a specific folder the Backslash convert the first char of the file name to "x0" and compiler handle the code as escape sequence
such as :

```
file = open("D:\python1\venom.txt")
```

and the output will be :

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\python1\x0benom.txt'
```

Comment: Same mistake, You should use ```r"D:\python1\venom.txt"``` or ```"D:\\python1\\venom.txt"``` or ```"D:/python1/venom.txt"```. ```\v``` is an escape sequence for "ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184100/how-does-v-differ-from-x0b-or-x0c

Comment: thank you I tried the first and it's work